# Image resizing in Windows IIS7 Data Center Edition

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, vbscript

I tried installing my old ASPImage from server Objects in my new server, but the object is not created even though the dll is registered and ASP is enabled in IIS7. Does anyone have any ideas on this issue, or used a different component that can be called from VBS as well as ASP classic?

I tried running tests on the object and it returns internal server errors. When running in VBS, no errors but it ignores the object.

Thanks
James F.

Comment: Just FYI, when creating the object, I get Invalid Access to memory Location. I have verified that IIS_IUSR has rights to the dll file as well as the folder the dll is in.

Comment: Most errors that start with 0x8007 can be looked up with NET HELPMSG
<decimal>

0x03E6 hexadecimal = 998 decimal

NET HELPMSG 998 returns "Invalid access to memory location."

This usually indicates a bug in the component that is being instantiated, so you need to obtain support for that component

Comment: in your application pool have you enabled 32-bit-applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a 64 bit Web Server, you have to enable the setting "Enable 32-Bit Applications" in the Application Pool using the 32bit Component.

See here for further details:
http://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1114/how-to-enable-32-bit-application-pool-iis-7-dedicatedvps.aspx